# Get ConversationId from Context

Tags: c#, botframework

How can I get the `ConversationId` from the `IDialogContext context`? I know that there is a `ConverationData` property but that seems to just be a data bag that can hold anything.

Is the id in this bag? If so, what is the key to retrieve it?

```
public async Task General(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
{
    //how can I access the conversationId here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So I have found a way of doing it but I am not sure if it is the best way.

The `context` object that is passed in has a `data` field on it which contains the original `message` object which in turn contains the `ConversationId`. Unfortuantely this is private.

But the `context` does have a `CreateMessage` method which returns a `Message` object which contains the `ConversationId` and it is accessible.

```
var id = context.MakeMessage().ConversationId;
```

Like I said, I am not sure if this is the best way but it is the only way I have been able to achieve this. I'll leave this up in case someone has a better way.

Comment: Well, current SDK doesn't have that anymore in the `IMessageActivity` returned from `context.MakeMessage()` ☹ . Do you know another way?

Answer (score 1):

With the last version of the framework you can get it from the DialogContext object easier:

```
var conversationId = context.Activity.Conversation.Id;
```

I used it and it worked on my bot.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this code:

```
var id = context.MakeMessage().Conversation.Id;
```

`Id` is now property in `Conversation` object. It works for me.