# Get token for given conversation ID

Tags: c#, botframework, direct-line-botframework

Let us assume :

- An iframe embedded in a webpage for chatting with Bot.
- Every time we refresh the page, a new conversation ID is assigned(c# bot solution with SDK's being used provided by microsoft. Microsoft Bot builder).
- I need to get a token(secret) for the specific conversation ID mentioned above.
- Note : we already have the conversation ID and Direct line secret on Azure, using these i need to get token to send messages to chat window asynchronously.

How do i get the token using Direct Line API 3.0, any ideas?

Comment: refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37251597/get-conversationid-from-context

Comment: I have the conversation ID, I need a token using Direct Line API 3.0 for the specific conv ID

Comment: API of direct line needs conversation id only see this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-direct-line-3-0-send-activity?view=azure-bot-service-3.0

Comment: Yes, but the header also contains Authorization which is a token

Comment: check my answer and links mention

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a way to do the same,

Please refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-connector-send-and-receive-messages?view=azure-bot-service-3.0

We need to make use of serviceUrl

Answer (score 1):

If you want to generate token you can do this way

[Refer this More HelpFull](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-direct-line-3-0-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-3.0)

Generates a token that is valid for one conversation.

```
POST /v3/directline/tokens/generate


Refreshes the token.

POST /v3/directline/tokens/refresh
```

[Whole Description](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-direct-line-3-0-api-reference?view=azure-bot-service-3.0#token-operations)

Comment: This is what even I am following, but every time the generate API is used. It generates its own new conversation ID. But I already have conversation ID for which I have to generate token

Comment: Yes, I do need to maintain the context when refreshed but then is after I have done the stuff mentioned next. I simple terms, I need to generate a token for an existing conversation ID and I will be doing it for the first time so there is no scope of refresh :).

Comment: Can you please give me more info @Tanmoy